# Is it possible to pass /dev/urandom through from the host to a qemu/kvm guest?

Tags: kvm-virtualization, qemu, random-number-generator

I'd like to pass the host's `/dev/urandom` device through to a qemu/kvm virtual machine.

Note that /dev/urandom is not seekable, so it's not possible to pass it through as a block device using `-hda`, `-fda`, or `-sda`.

I would expect that I should be able to pass it through as a serial device, but I can't see to get that working.  The guest needs to be able to read random data from some device in /dev where that random data is served by the host.

I am well aware of `virtio-rng` in modern versions of qemu/kvm and that's not quite what I'm looking for.

Comment: Why do you want to do this?  The guest OS should have its own random number generator...

Comment: I can see a way to do what you are asking but it seems terribly kludgy: cron script pulls a buffers worth of data on host OS into a file (cat), copy it into a file which has a filesystem (dd mke2fs cp), which is loop mounted and shared into kvm to its guest ... yuck.

Answer (score 4):

For `/dev/urandom` you don't need to do anything.

For `/dev/random` KVM provides a [paravirtualized random number generator](http://www.mnementh.co.uk/home/projects/collabora/virtio-rng) to its (Linux) guests. This allows guests to use the host's entropy pool. To use it, make sure that [HW_RANDOM_VIRTIO](http://cateee.net/lkddb/web-lkddb/HW_RANDOM_VIRTIO.html) is set in your guest kernel configuration.

Comment: Read the first paragraph, then.

Comment: Okay, so virtio-rng is a module.  It loads via modprobe.  Now what?  Should that create a new device, or just populate /dev/random?

Comment: Now you edit your question to clarify it.

Comment: Yes, I am well aware of virtio-rng.  And I'm well aware that a guest has its own /dev/urandom.  What I want, however, as my question asks, is to literally pass the host's /dev/urandom to the guest and have it readable as a serial device.

Comment: Sorry, but when you ask for something that sounds like a very bad idea here, you are going to be asked about it, and should be prepared to justify it. We have a very strong culture of "do it right or not at all" here.

Comment: The question asks, "Is it possible..." to do something very specific.  I've read the documentation.  I've contacted the QEMU upstream developers.  I haven't found the answer I'm looking for, and so I turned to StackExchange.  If the answer to my question is "no", and that can be justified, I'm perfectly fine with that.    I'll gladly +1 that, and select as the correct answer.

Comment: Again, that's because you're almost certainly asking the wrong question and need to rethink what you're doing.